# User Property does not export despite "success"

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service

I'm working with a SharePoint 2010 Server and added the [initials] property to my User Profile Properties and set it to export [initials] in my Active Directory.
But changing the value and running the incremental synchronization, doesn't work

I checked the Forefront Identity Manager and it says, old value and new value:
[image: Old Value D | new Value DG]
It also says success, but the value is not replicated into the active directory.
[image: DeltaImport Success]

I already tried to re-add the property but nothing works.

Any Ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: did you try to run a full crawl?

Comment: I try to avoid a full synchronization, because there are some differences between the AD and the SharePoint Profile, only as a last resort